# How can it be that when I am connected to wify network localhost requests use DNS?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-8, redirection, localhost

When I am connected to local wi-fi networck requests like `http://localhost:63342/prototype/index-3.html` redirect me to some web page. When I turn wi-fi off it stips and works as normal (hosted on my machine web server). **How to to stop such thing?** Use of     `127.0.0.1       localhost` in hosts file also does not make any difference.

dot after localhosts resolves in: same web page with same warning (111) Connection refused and any nonexisting webaddress 0.0.0.0, 127.0.0.1 etc resolves int same/similar page of error/warning of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a dot after `localhost`, like this: `http://localhost.:63342/prototype/index-3.html`

Technically, fully-qualified domain names are supposed to end in a dot: `www.example.com.` If you leave off the final dot, your DNS resolver software may assume you've only specified a partial hostname and you want your resolver software to append your "search domain(s)" to the end of it. This was intended to make it easy to go to your favorite hosts at your own site by just typing their hostname without bothering to fully qualify it. So you could type `www` to get to your own web server, instead of having to type `www.example.com.`. But when then Internet started to become popular among consumers in the mid to late 1990's, few people learned about appending the final dot, so people putting in `www.example.com`, who already had `example.com` set as their search domain, would end up generating spurious DNS lookups for `www.example.com.example.com.`.

I think that may be what's happening to you here. You're just specifying `localhost` and your DNS resolver is assuming you want to append your search domain, so it's sending out a query for `localhost.example.com.`, and your DNS server is using wildcard matching to replace "NXDOMAIN" (non-existent domain; domain not found) results with a bogus resolution to an IP address of some server they want to "redirect" you to.

If you specify the final dot, your resolver should realize `localhost.` **is** the fully-qualified domain name, and should find it in `/etc/hosts` instead of asking the DNS server for `localhost.example.com.`.

Comment: dot after localhosts resolves in: same web page with same warning `(111) Connection refused` and any nonexisting webaddress 0.0.0.0, 127.0.0.1 etc resolves int same/similar page of error/warning of some sort.